# How to call another functions returned value into a new function?

Tags: python, function, return

I'm just having some trouble with a function. I have written one function:

```
def dep():
  d = int(input("when did the employee depart? Please enter response in military time 0 - 2400 "))
  while (d < 0 or d > 2400):
      d= int(input("Please enter a valid number "))
return d
```

And in a later function, I want the value d. As seen here:

```
def mealDep(): 
  dep = dep() 

  if dep <= 700 and dep > 0:
```

I know now that I can't just call and assign dep() to a variable, but then how do I get the value that's been returned?

Comment: while you shouldn't do `dep = dep()` as that will reassign the name `dep`, you could do `somevar = dep()`.  Also check the indentation of the return statement. It currently is not in the function (though that may just be a stackoverflow display issue).

Comment: I'd also recommend catching the error that will inevitably happen when the user enters text rather than a number.

Comment: "I know now that I can't just call and assign dep() to a variable" um, of course you can do that.

Comment: Sorry, I didn't think I could. I was tying to find it online but I see from user155 that I was supposed to not name the variable the same as the function.

Answer (score 0):

I went and cleaned up a couple of errors and made other things better practice. In addition to shadowing your own function with `dep = ...`, there were a couple other things like not safely casting user input. Hope this helps.

```
def get_departure_time():  # verbosity is GOOD 99% of the time

    while True:
        # Get the raw input first
        departure_time = input("When did the employee depart? Please enter response in military time 0 - 2400:")

        # THEN validate. This prevents your code from breaking from type conversion
        try:
            departure_time = int(departure_time)
            assert departure_time > 0 and departure_time < 2400

            break # Breaks out of the infinite loop, and returns below

        except (ValueError, AssertionError):
            print("Please enter response in military time 0 - 2400.")
            continue

    return departure_time

def meal_dep(): #  snek_case > camelback case
    departure_time = get_departure_time() 

    if departure_time <= 700 and departure_time > 0:
        ...
```

Comment: So as long as the variable in the second function is the same name as the return variable in the first function, it'll work?

Comment: @Jay, no that has nothing to do with it. Variable names are a convenience to the programmer. If you wanted you could write: `foo = get_departure_time()` or `not_departure_time = get_departure_time()` and it would work all the same.